# What's happened to Wedge Antilles in the Sequel era?

Tags: star-wars

While reading this [article](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178248/whats-lando-been-up-to-during-the-new-trilogy), I started reading about Wedge Antilles later life, after the Battle of Jakku. In his [Wookieepedia bio](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles), it states at the end that he retired:

> Following the signing of the Galactic Concordance, Wedge was made the head instructor of a new flight academy on the planet Hosnian Prime.

As most viewers will know, [Hosnian Prime](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hosnian_Prime) has not had a [happy history](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hosnian_Cataclysm) in the Sequel series. So was Wedge still teaching on Hosnian Prime

> when it was destroyed by the First Order?

Has he been helping the Resistance? Are there any other details as to **what Wedge Antilles has been doing during the Sequel trilogy?**

Comment: During his retirement he finally rested, and watched the sunrise on an grateful universe. Ooops wrong franchise...

Comment: Probably dead. The republic worlds were destroyed, and the resistance has one ship-load of people left.

Comment: The Republic capitol and its system was destroyed (along with their fleet, which they idiotically put all in one place).  'The republic worlds were destroyed' implies every world in the New Republic was destroyed, which was far from what happened.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As we see in *The Rise of Skywalker*, he is alive and well prior to the assault on Exegol. He is only there for a second, but [Denis Lawson](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0493200/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) did reprise his role for a cameo.

> Wedge Antilles was one of the Rebellion’s greatest
> heroes. He answered Calrissian’s call and journeyed to Exegol to fight the
> Final Order, serving as a gunner on the Millennium Falcon—the same ship
> that had helped him destroy the second Death Star at Endor
>
> [image: Close-up of a grey-haired Wedge wearing a headset, hands on the controls of his gun.]
>
> <sub><sup>[*Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a second source that confirms what ship he was on (and a nice pic)

Answer (score 6):

We now know that he survived the new trilogy (he was on the Falcon when it attacked the force on Exegol) but we also know what he's been up to in the meantime. In [Star Wars: Aftermath - Empire's End](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Empire%27s_End) when we learn that he was heading up the flight school on Hosnian Prime.

> Conder leans forward and says to Temmin: “A mouse droid tells me that the New Republic is setting up a new flight academy on Hosnian Prime. And I hear you’ll be a pupil there, is that right?”
>
> ...
>
> “I’m going with him,” Norra says. Eyebrows arch in curiosity, and she answers their unspoken questions with, “Oh, relax. It’s not like that, I’m not the dutiful mother unable to let go of her star-pupil son. Wedge will be the head instructor there, at least to get the school set up.

Evidently he was away from the Hosnian System [when it went all 'splodey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hzll.gif).

Comment: RIP Wedge my favorite character. You didn't deserve to go out like that. Only pilot to survive both Death Star runs and personal friend of Leia Organa and Luke Skywalker not even recruited into the so-called Resistance.

Comment: @WraithLeader - If they can convince the actor to show up in a future film, it'll be "revealed" that he was offworld at the time of the cataclysm

Comment: I know all about the troubles with the actor, I'm just lamenting we never have gotten to see ice-in-vein Wedge like he was in the X-Wing series. Favorite books and stories so it's personal for me.

Comment: @WraithLeader I know what you mean. It's a damn shame no one has realized how cool an adaptation would be.

Comment: @Valorum It would be strange if New Republic had only bases in Hosian System. Rebels, Republic, Empire - all fractions had bases in many system, so we may have hope that Wedge was in other system

Comment: just because there are issues w/ the actor doesn't mean he can't continue on in canon books, comics, and web series. He may show up in the new canon series Resistance - which is heavily flying based

Comment: @NKCampbell - The thinking seems to be that if the actor doesn't want to reprise, the studio isn't going to push the issue where the films are concerned. You're right that he may turn up in a further book or cartoon.

Comment: indeed - the character appeared in Rebels (granted, that was a pre-New Hope incarnation, but indicative of the character's ability to appear in other canon media w/out the involvement of Denis Lawson)